# Rewrite nginx url using rewrite directive

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite my url in nginx..

my code

```
location /test {
        rewrite ^/test/(.*) /$1 last;
        proxy_pass http://example.com;
    }
```

full url looks like: 127.0.0.1/test/example.com

I want the 127.0.0.1/test/ to be removed and the request to be redirected to example.com directly

Can anybody please help??

Comment: just to understand it correctly: so lets say you point your browser to http://127.0.0.1/test/ and this request to your localhost shall directly redirect to "http://example.com"?

Comment: @PeterSmith yes exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this simple permanent redirect:

```
location /test {
   return 301 http://example.com;
}
```

edit: using a redirect rule, you could do:

```
rewrite ^/test/(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 redirect;
```

the above rewrite rule rewrites everything from */test/XYZ* or just */test/* to *http://example.com/* respectively to *https://example.com/XYZ* .

Comment: sure, you're welcome! sometimes the easiest way is the best solution :)

Comment: can you please tell me if i can do the same thing using 'rewrite directive??'

Comment: thanks.. that works too.. but as you said easiest way is the best solution :)

Comment: yep :) you can of course modify the rewrite so that it works without additions like _XYZ_ but this gives you an example of how you could achieve your requirement. There are also a lot of discussions what the best method is, using a permanent redirect or involving a rewrite rule. This (imho) also depends on the required performance. A rewrite rule might consume more CPU in high frequently accessed environments than a permanent redirect.